# Exporting variable from case Warning

Tags: erlang, warnings, case-statement

When developing with erlang, I sometimes use case statements like this

```
case Status of
    1 ->
        Variable = "Something";
    2 ->
        Variable = "Something else";
    3 ->
        Variable = {"Something very different", [1,2,3]}
end
```

to assign a value to a variable depending on some condition.

The problem is: if I use it after the case statement:

```
do_something(Variable),
```

I get a compilation warning:

```
Warning: variable 'Variable' exported from 'case'
```

What is the best practice in Erlang to assign values to variables depending on some conditions and avoid such warnings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this in Erlang is to assign `Variable` the return value of `case` since `case` is an expression that returns the last expression's value from each branch:

```
Variable = case Status of
    1 -> "Something";
    2 -> "Something else";
    3 -> {"Something very different", [1,2,3]}
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This warning is not activated by default.  You have to turn it on with the `warn_export_vars` option.  For example, putting the code above into `foo.erl`:

```
$ erlc foo.erl
```

(no warning there)

```
$ erlc +warn_export_vars foo.erl
foo.erl:14: Warning: variable 'Variable' exported from 'case' (line 6)
```

I happen to think that there's nothing wrong per se with setting variables like this, so I don't turn that option on.  (It's possible to write easy-to-read or hard-to-read code using either convention.)